# How to disable creating a new python IDLE session when compiling through Notepad++?

Tags: python, shell, notepad++

when I'm compiling `python` through `Notepad++` I get a new python shell ( `IDLE` ) everytime, but I rather just keep one fixed window, instead of a new window on another position.

So for example, when I write a script which prints "Hello World!" and compile it so that my Python Shell displays the text, and when I modify my script to "Goodbye World!" the same shell prints that text. Or that that shell gets closed, but that at the same position a new shell emerges with the new text.

Could somebody please help me I'm having a hard time figuring this out..
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You might have noticed, that `python` source code does not require a compilation to get run. Python source-code is rather beeing interpreted on-the-fly, by the language "engine".

Your issue is related with the `Notepad++` settings and O/S settings.

**`IDLE`** is a program, that has typically been set in O/S as an associated-application to a set of filename-extensions ( **`.py`**, etc )

If your Notepad++ <kbd>Compile</kbd> does not call O/S to "launch" a file, the problem ceases to exist.

Your normal step to "run" the file then would be to just re-type inside the `python` terminal, whenever you have saved any code-modification in `Notepad++`:

```
>>> execfile( "<<_whatever_filename_my_python_source_has_>>" ) # local DIR
>>> execfile( "C:\\someDIR\\anotherSubDIR\\runMyPYTHON.py" )   # doubled-slashes
```